# Creating a Python OOP tree (decision-tree) with multiple child nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, data-structures, tree

Suppose I have a tree data structure, how would i go about structuring a tree in this OOP tree format from the link below. I am confused on how to dedicate a certain number of child nodes from certain parent nodes, as it is not just a left and right format.

A sample format is below (not of the whole tree). The customer needs to choose to order or not, then they have 3 product categories to choose from, with 6 products in each, and from each product, they choose the size of either small, medium or large, and then a quantity of 1 2 or 3.

```
                                                           'Order'

                              ******************/************************************************\

                          Yes***********Yes***********************Yes****************************No
                   /                     /                         /
         Category: Hot Drink,       Cold Drink,                   Food

            ///                         ///

  Tea, Mocha, HotChoc      Iced Tea, Iced Mocha, Iced HotChoc
  /      /       /             /        /           \

S,M,L  S,M,L   S,M,L      S,M,L        S,M,L       S,M,L

 /  /  /

  1,2,3 1,2,3, 1,2,3
```

Here is the documentation from http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch21.html

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, cargo, left=None, right=None):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.left  = left
        self.right = right

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cargo)
```

Comment: You might consider representing each tree as a dictionary, mapping the names of branches to the subtrees.

Comment: I have tried doing this with my recent post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424290/building-a-decision-tree-using-user-inputs-for-ordering-goods/59426574#59426574 but was told using an OOp framework was better? Please could u expand

Comment: Looking at your original question, it looks like you're trying to fit 3 decisions into one tree (product, size, and quantity).  I think your original solution would be a lot clearer if you split those into 3 trees, and combined the results. This looks like a bit of an XY problem: what is the use that you see this structure having?

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable quantity of arguments; then build a list from the variable arg iterator.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, cargo, *children):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.children = list(children)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cargo)
```